# Absolute positioning over tableView, view hierarchy and redrawing

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uiview, uinavigationcontroller

on the main screen on my project I have a a TableView, with a navigationBar on top and toolBar on the bottom. The thing is, one of the buttons in the toolbar needs to slide up an UISegmentedControl from the toolbar. I have already implemented this control in a custom UIView, BUT, if i just add it to my rootviewcontroller.view and slide it into place, it will scroll with the rest of the table, which is undesired (I would like it to appear as an extension of the toolbar).

So, what do I do? In rootViewController I do

```
self.filterView = [[FilterView alloc] initWithTarget:self.tableView reloadDataSelector:@selector(reloadData)];
[[self.view superview] addSubview:self.filterView];
[[self.view superview] bringSubviewToFront:self.filterView];
```

I add the control view (self.filterView) to my view's superview, and that puts it above the tableview's scroll.

BUT, now the problem. As soon as the tableView goes out of view (I push another view on the navigationController, or specially if the app goes to background) this view gets re layed-out, and my controller view gets moved to (0,0).

The thing is, as far as pushing new views on the navigationController, I can kind of control it by repositioning it in viewWillAppear and viewWillDisappear in my rootViewController. But when the app goes to background and comes back those functions don't get called.

So, is there any way to

(a)prevent my controller view from being moved

(b)detecting when it has been moved unintentionally

(c)detecting coming and going from background from rootViewController

???

I know I can detect passes to background in appDelegate, but I wouldn't feel comfortable dealing with layout issues there.

Thanks!!

**EDIT:**

To add some info, if I do

```
NSLog(@"%@",[self.view superview]); 

//I get <UIViewControllerWrapperView: 0x61589d0; frame = (0 64; 320 372); autoresize = W+H; layer = <CALayer: 0x615d9c0>>
```

**EDIT2:** I guess I could create my own wrapper UIView first, load all my current view hierarchy in it, and put the controller view there. Do you guys think that would be worth the trouble? isn't there a simpler way?

**EDIT3:** Ended up opting for changing my rootViewController from UITableViewController to UIViewController, and added the tableView programatically, as Phil suggested below. I can now control my main view as I like, and since I am putting my segmentedControl view there I can control how it is positioned, as opposed to before, when I was placing it in an UIViewControllerWrapperView, which I am not too sure who controls or what it does to it's subviews.

SO, just out of curiosity, does anyone know why the UIViewControllerWrapperView that was wrapping my UITableViewController's view was moving my UIView on coming back from background??

To clarify, the setup was like so:

```
UIViewControllerWrapperView
  |
  |UITableView
  |Custom SegmentedControl UIView
```

Comment: what is self.view superview in this case ?

Comment: @Matt I am honestly not entirely sure, as this is kind of an experiment. However, i get `<UIViewControllerWrapperView: 0x61589d0; frame = (0 64; 320 372); autoresize = W+H; layer = <CALayer: 0x615d9c0>>` if I do `NSLog(@"%@", [self.view superview]);`

Maybe I should load my ViewController Inside my own container UIView from the beginning and add the controllerView there?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As a side note, you have a pattern in your code that looks like that view is going to leak and addSubview will automatically put the view on the top of the view order.

However, the reason your view is scrolling is because it is being added as a subview of the UITableView, which is a subclass of UIScrollView. When the scroll view scrolls, it will move any subviews up or down by the contentOffset property. As the UIScrollView scrolls it will repeatedly layout its subviews. Since the table view isn't aware of your custom subview, it appears it is just moving it to the 0,0.

I assume you are using UITableViewController. If you plan to have more than just a table view for this view controller, then you should implement a standard view controller instead. This controller would have a normal view that contains the tableview and your other views. UITableViewController is merely for convenience for a very common case.

It's very easy to duplicate UITableViewController's functionality if you are worried about that. It is actually very clearly documented.

> When the table view is about to appear
>   the first time it’s loaded, the
>   table-view controller reloads the
>   table view’s data. It also clears its
>   selection (with or without animation,
>   depending on the request) every time
>   the table view is displayed. The
>   UITableViewController class implements
>   this in the superclass method
>   viewWillAppear:. You can disable this
>   behavior by changing the value in the
>   clearsSelectionOnViewWillAppear
>   property.

In your implementation:

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];

    if ([self.tableView numberOfSections] == 0) {
        [self.tableView reloadData];
    } else {
        [self.tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:[self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow] animated:animated];
    }
}
```

> When the table view has appeared, the
>   controller flashes the table view’s
>   scroll indicators. The
>   UITableViewController class implements
>   this in the superclass method
>   viewDidAppear:.

In your implementation:

```
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];
    [self.tableView flashScrollIndicators];
}
```

> It implements the superclass method
>   setEditing:animated: so that if a user
>   taps an Edit|Done button in the
>   navigation bar, the controller toggles
>   the edit mode of the table.

In your implementation:

```
- (void)setEditing:(BOOL)editing animated:(BOOL)animated {
    [super setEditing:editing animated:animated];
    [self.tableView setEditing:editing animated:animated];
}
```

Comment: Hey man, thanks for your comment. You didn't quite get what I was trying to explain, because I'm not adding my controller to a tableView, but to it's superview, so it's not scrolling with it. The problem I'm having is this layout get's screwed up coming back from background.

Anyways, you make a good point about adding the tableView as a subView in a general ViewController

Comment: Hey, in the end I opted to do that, just changed rootviewcontroller to a uiviewcontroller, added the uitableview programatically on loading, and the controller view too, so they ended up as siblings in the view hierarchy as before, but now in a uiview I know and can control.
If you dont mind I'd like to keep the question open in case anyone knows why the UIViewControllerWrapperView was moving my UIView from place when coming back from background. Just out of curiosity. 
Ill accept your answer tomorrow.
Thanks a lot.